# com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat always throws ParseException

Tags: java, decimalformat, parseexception

With the following code I only want to allow positive numbers. For some reason i am not even able to parse the strings correctly:

```
DecimalFormat dfNoNegative = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
dfNoNegative.setNegativePrefix("");
try {
    System.out.println(dfNoNegative.parse("123.00"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(e.getErrorOffset());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error message and ErrorOffset:

```
Unparseable number: "123.00"
6
```

Can anyone guide me where I am mistaken? An example for a working String would be good as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to `dfNoNegative.setNegativePrefix("");` to nothing (`""`). This doesn't work, because the String started directly with the number and `123` is not `""`, and therefore it fails. Basically this method overwrites what should be used as negative prefix (default is `-`). If you set it to `!` as example, `System.out.println(dfNoNegative.parse("!123.00"));` would print `-123`.